# B2C - How to Trigger a Click on a create account link

Tags: javascript, jquery, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I used this [documentation](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/split-email-verification-and-signup) to split email verification and signup.

On the authentication page, I would like to trigger a click on the creation account  link when the variable param = true (retrieved from another js file in localStorage).

the param variable has true value but the click does not triggered.
The same code works in a simple html and js page.

JS code

```
if (localStorage.getItem('param') == 'true') {
            alert(localStorage.getItem('param')); //true value but don't execute the click function
            localStorage.setItem('param', false);
            document.getElementById("createAccount").click();
}
```

[image]

How can I do it please.

Comment: Did you call after document.ready()?

Comment: Yes it works with document.ready()...
Thanks @JasSuri-MSFT :)

Answer (score 0):

***Thanks [@Jas Suri - MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8357357/jas-suri-msft) for pointing OP in the right direction. Posting it as an answer to help other community members.***

Include **`document.ready()`** method that is used to prevent other code from running till the document is completely loaded.

> **Please [note](https://www.w3schools.in/jquery/document-ready-event) that there is a chance that your jQuery code won't work if you don't use  **`document.ready()`****

So, to trigger a click on a create account link, make sure to run your code after calling **`document.ready()`** .

Check this [link](https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/document-ready-in-jquery/) to know how to use **`document.ready()`** .